# How to change log level in quarkus application deployed on kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, logging, quarkus

I have a quarkus application with a standard configuration. The application works as expected, in my local develop environment i'm able to set the log level by setting

```
# application.property
quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.min-level=INFO
```

when i deploy the application on kunernetes i'm not able to set the log level to INFO and the application logs everything in DEBUG mode.

How i can set the log level on the app ?

Below some logs

```
13:41:17.639 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG notprivacysafe.graphql.execution.Execution - Executing '9243991163' query operation: 'QUERY' using 'graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy' execution strategy
13:41:17.647 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe'...
13:41:17.648 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/id'...
13:41:17.648 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/nomeCampo'...
13:41:17.648 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/tipoLista'...
13:41:17.648 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/cdr'...
13:41:17.649 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/descrizione'...
13:41:17.649 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy - '9243991163' completing field '/defaultListe[0]/attivo'...
13:41:17.649 [executor-thread-1] DEBUG graphql.GraphQL - Execution '9243991163' completed with zero errors
```

I found the logs below when i copy the other logs, i will investigate on that

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jboss/lib/main/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/jboss/lib/main/org.jboss.slf4j.slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
13:37:09.731 [Thread-0] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
13:37:09.742 [Thread-0] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
```

---

UPDATE

We exclude from maven a dependency that caused a wrong binding

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-ImportXHTML</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
...
```

Comment: You mean that setting to `DEBUG` does not work?

Comment: Nope...settings to INFO not works.

Comment: Can you enhance the question with some of the logging output?

Comment: Yes..i paste some logs (simple debug logs). And i found some initial logs with something to investigate

Comment: Problem solved it was the binding of SLF4J. We had a dependency with another binding of SLF4J and for some reason, in the Kubernetes environment, the app starts with the wrong one. We exclude the second binding and the logs are correct.